# What do I need to do to make Gradle build my release APK faster?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Android Studio v3.1.4, with the Gradle plugin at v3.2.0. I have the following settings in my `gradle.properties` file:

- `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M`
- `org.gradle.daemon=true`
- `org.gradle.parallel=true`
- `android.enableR8=false` (I'm not using R8 yet)

My app also depends on the Support Libraries, GMS Play Services (Location, Analytics, Ads, Auth), and Firebase (In-app Messaging, Messaging, Core, Auth, Database), among other dependencies (including Multidex, Glide, Facebook's Android SDK, GPUImage Library, and more).

Currently, I'm trying to build a Release APK, and I've been stuck in the `transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProdRelease` for more than 30 minutes. There were other bottlenecks, of course, like `processProdReleaseSources` and `compileProdReleaseJavaWithJavac`, but they took nowhere as long as 30 minutes.

What can I do to make the build process faster, other than what I've listed above (except the disable R8 part)?

Comment: How large is your app? How much memory does your machine have? How fast is your network connection?

Comment: The last time I built a debug APK, it came up to ~21 MB. My machine has 8 GB of memory (actually 4 GB, but with a 4GB extension). My network's quite fast... if it doesn't decide to kick me randomly.

Answer (score 0):

He's always seen my job

```
Build>Clean Project
```

and

```
Build>Rebuild Project
```

Comment: I guess I'll try that, and with R8 and gradle caching. Though... I got this feeling that this solution is like the Windows Reboot.

Comment: did it help you?

Comment: I did manage to build an APK with those settings and after cleaning and rebuilding. Though, my laptop took around 25 minutes in total, with the dexing taking 21 minutes.